# Terminating the mariadb service in between when the engine is running

Tags: go

My application is connected to Maria Db on a different server, So once I start my engine It fetches data by querying into the database, What I am trying to do is, my application queries from DB for every 5sec
I just terminated the maria DB service by this

```
service mariadb stop
```

After doing this In my application where I am executing the query thrown this error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x54c9a6]

goroutine 50 [running]:
database/sql.(*Rows).close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/go1.14/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:3063 +0x76
database/sql.(*Rows).Close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/go1.14/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:3059 +0x33
panic(0x8d03e0, 0xf3dd00)
    /home/go1.14/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x166
database/sql.(*Rows).Next(0x0, 0x1)
    /home/go1.14/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2744 +0x30
path-to-file/loadConfig.LoadFromDB(0x9ff760, 0xc0000240a0, 0xc000192000, 0xf, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    path-to-file/loadConfig/loadConfig.go:65 +0x1a2
```

My code looks like this:

```
func LoadFromDB(Ctx context.Context, Conn *sql.DB, modId int) (map[string][]string, map[string]string, error) {
    rows, err := Conn.Query(getQueryFromFile("QUERY"),modId)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("LOAD CONFIG: Error establishing connection to DB")
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    configValues := make(map[string][]string)
    configTimeVal := make(map[string]string)
    for rows.Next() {
        configParam := ""
        configVal := ""
        var configLastUpdated string
        eror := rows.Scan(&configParam, &configVal, &configLastUpdated)
        if eror != nil {
            return nil, nil, eror
        } else {
            configValues[configParam] = append(configValues[configParam], configVal)
            configTimeVal[configParam] = configLastUpdated
        }
    }

        return configValues, configTimeVal, nil
    }
```

Can you guys help me on how to handle this situation when the maria db service is stopped

Comment: Don't continue on error from `Query`, and check `rows.Err()` every iteration. See [example in the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows)

Comment: okay. Got it  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `return` when the error is non-nil, so the function just keeps running. Try this:

```golang
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("LOAD CONFIG: Error establishing connection to DB")
        return nil, nil, err
    }
```

You also need to handle errors from the `Next()` function; see the docs:

> Next prepares the next result row for reading with the Scan method. It returns true on success, or false if there is no next result row or an error happened while preparing it. Err should be consulted to distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: Okay, I missed that one. Thanks :)